# Managing write access through cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like for people to "vote" on things without having to be logged in. The way I'm thinking of doing this is via a cookie.

What would be a recommended way for tracking these cookies per a post?

E.g, a user views a post, and then "votes it." Now that post vote is stored in a cookie and when that user visits that page it'll say they voted for it.

Should I create a cookie per post, or a cookie that is a hash of all the posts they voted on?

Tips/examples of code would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Be aware that Rails caps cookies at 4kb, and a user can vote multiple times by just clearing their cookies.

Comment: Yes, a user can also register multiple times, so that isn't the issue for me. I'd like to be able to have people vote without registering. If not cookie any other way? How to manage that cookie?

Comment: What if instead of storing an array of posts in a cookie, it's a collection of votes stored by a cookie id?

Comment: A collection of votes stored by cookie ID is probably more viable if you expect you could break that 4k cap, yeah.

Comment: So what I'm doing right now is creating a basic User model and associating a user_id with a cookie if it exists... hopefully this does the job! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can access cookies via `cookies[:cookie_name]`. More details here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going in the right direction, cookies are made for this type needs only for storing insensitive information like the search history. Just remember not to give the cookie any expire time and it will remain stored in the users browser, and most of the normal users won't be clearing cookies so it will not be a problem for you.

you can use it like this `cookies[:voted] = true` put this when you register a vote, and every time before voting check this

```
if cookies[:voted]
  return # or show that you have already voted
```

if you also want to save the vote that they caste last time you can just save that in the cookie for retrieving the next time.